# Strange pixels showing up in programs

Tags: windows-8, graphics-card, pixels

So I just got my new pc and I noticed that there are a lot of multicolored pixels all over certain programs like shown in the screenshot:

[image]

This is on my brand new Asus rog g750jm-ds71. These pixels are static, they dont move btw. I have tried switching the default graphics processor for Steam (One of the effected programs) from my Nvidia GeForce GTX 860M to my integrated graphics (Intel HD Graphics 4600) but still no luck there. I have tried searching this on many websites and have found similar issues but none are exactly the same or extremely close to the same as my issue. Any suggestions?

Comment: What other programs have you noticed are affected?

Comment: I noticed that Origin was also having similar issues but they seemed to resolve itself, this one has not change in the slightest